# A "Loading..." caption while reloading textures in opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es

Android+OpenGL ES.

When the opengl context is lost (which happens every time the phones falls asleep or the ad is shown) I need to recreate my opengl textures. It usually takes 2-3 seconds (which is also bad but I didn't find a convenient way to avoid losing the opengl context) so I need to display some caption like "Loading..." instead of the black screen. 
I can't think of a way to do this.
Drawing at the very beggining of SurfaceCreated (where I also recreate the textures) doesn't seem to work - the screen is still black.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Comment: in onDraw(or similar) do `if(loaded) drawTheGame() else drawLoadingMsg()` ... use different thread to load the resorces and start it in SurfaceCreated ... after resources are loaded set loaded :)

Comment: seems so obvious now, i feel so dumb :) thanks a lot :)

Comment: (Just in case someone needs this)
By the way, I had to split my texture loading code into two parts. The first one, containing "BitmapFactory.decodeResource() etc..." is the part to be stored in the other thread. And the part with GenTextures() HAS to be stored in the opengl-thread.